# I want to pass the text input value to the post ajax call. The javascript function to allow only numbers dot and comma

Tags: javascript, ajax

The below first function code is working absolutely fine for number and dot. However, I want to include comma as well.
This value is stored in an array along with other parameters.

I have also tried the below mentioned 2nd code. It accepts the dot,comma and number only however it stores values as "12.345%2C78" instead of "12.345,78"

```
    function isNumberandComma(evt) {
    var iKeyCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode
    if (iKeyCode != 46 && iKeyCode > 31 && (iKeyCode < 48 || iKeyCode > 57)){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

```
 function isNumberandComma(evt) {
     const NUM_0 = 48;
    const NUM_9 = 57;
    const KEY_COMMA = 188;
    const KEY_DELETE = 46;
    const iKeyCode = evt.which || evt.keyCode;
   if (iKeyCode >= NUM_0 || iKeyCode <= NUM_9 || iKeyCode === KEY_COMMA || iKeyCode === KEY_DELETE){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: `function isNumberandComma(evt) { const iKeyCode = evt.which || evt.keyCode; return /[,\.\d]/.test(iKeyCode); }` or just test the whole stringe on click of the submit or whatever

Comment: This is allowing me to enter the data as required as well as the data is getting stored into array appropriately. Thsi value is stored in an array and passed to ajax Post call i.e. wcf service. The error that i get is "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: input". I am sure it is because of this value itself

Answer (score 0):

Replace your OR operator (`||`) with the AND operator (`&&`).

iKeyCode has to be > 48 AND < 57 OR == 188 OR == 46.

```
  if (iKeyCode >= 48 && iKeyCode <= 57 || iKeyCode === 188 || iKeyCode === 46) {
        return true;
  }
```

Comment: This is not allowing to enter comma in the input text box:                                           
 function isNumberandComma(evt) {
  var iKeyCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode
    if (iKeyCode >= 48 && iKeyCode <= 57 || iKeyCode === 188 || iKeyCode === 46) {
        return true;
  }
  return false;
}